# How do I scale a point cloud from a custom pivot point in AN?

Tags: animation-nodes

I have a cloud of points and I want to scale them from a custom pivot point? How can this be done with animation nodes.

Comment: maybe this quick answer helps (don't have much time now..): translate all points so that the scale pivot is the origin -> scale -> translate all poinrs in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thanks Jacquest that´s a good hack. I think I´m gonna try this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740507/extend-a-line-segment-a-specific-distance. Basically the answer where they give you this formula to calculate a 2D point. If the thing works I´ll write the anser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Jacques, translate the points such that the pivot becomes the origin, scale, undo the translation:

[image: Node Tree]

Undoing the translation can be done by multiplying by the *Invert Matrix* nodes.